# PHP multi directional arrays from a grid

Tags: php, arrays

I'm creating a crossword page on my site, I produce a grid (form) with 8 x 8 input boxes.  when I fill in the answers they are sent to a page to assess them but this is where i have the problems.

the values are sent using form method `GET`, so if the top line read q,w,e,r,t, , ,y  then it would pass this over like this :-

```
submit.php?0[0]=q&0[1]=w&0[2]=e&0[3]=r&0[4]=t&0[5]=&0[6]=&0[7]=y&1[0]
```

But when I put the values into an array, the empty values are left out, so when printing out the array it reads as "q,w,e,r,t,y" instead of "q,w,e,r,t, , ,y"

I currently fill the array like this :`-
$one = $_GET['0'];`

My HTML form is:

```
<form action='submit.php' method='get' name='xword' id='xword1'> <?php

$array=array(
    array("h","e","l","l","o","0","0","0"),
    array("e","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("l","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("l","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("o","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
    array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
);

$X = 0;
while ($X < "8") {
    $Y = 0;
    while ($Y < "8") {
        if ($array[$X][$Y] == "0") {
            echo "<input type='text' id='text' name='" . $X . "[$Y]' class='blank'>";
        } else {
            echo "<input type='text' id='text' name='" . $X . "[$Y]' class='text'>";
        }
        $Y++;
    }
    echo "<br />";
    $X++;
}
?> <input type='submit' value='Submit'>
```

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: I put the commas in to highlight where the spaces are expected to be.

Comment: Can you post the HTML code for your form?

Comment: <form action='submit.php' method='get' name='xword' id='xword1'>
<?php
$array=array(
 array("h","e","l","l","o","0","0","0"),
 array("e","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
 array("l","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
 array("l","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
 array("o","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
 array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
 array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
 array("0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"),
);

Comment: $X=0;
while ($X<"8") {
$Y=0;
while ($Y<"8") {
 if ($array[$X][$Y]=="0") {
 echo "<input type='text' id='text' name='" . $X . "[$Y]' class='blank'>";
 } else {
 echo "<input type='text' id='text' name='" . $X . "[$Y]' class='text'>";
 }
$Y++;
}
echo "<br />";
$X++;
}

?>
<input type='submit' value='Submit'>

Comment: I can't seem to be able to add a proper reply, only a small comment!

Comment: Please edit your question to include the code

Comment: I've gone ahead and edited your comment into your question, remember to use the `Edit` button next time! Alright lemme check why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks, I'll find my way around eventually!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't see the empty spaces within the array being left out.

> [image]

This is the output of `print_r($_GET)` when I type `qwer` in the first four text fields and `ty` in the last two in the first row.

Getting the data with `$one = $_GET['0'];` works fine (without quotes work too), and when I implode the first row, it outputs exactly what you had expected.

```
echo implode(', ', $_GET[0]);

OUTPUT: q, w, e, r, , , t, y
```

Comment: Thank you, that works.  is there a way to put it back into an array without the commas?

Comment: It is in an array, `$_GET[0]` represents the first row, and `$_GET[0][0]` is the first character in the first row. If you `print_r($_GET);` you can see the entire array representation.

Comment: Do you want to put all the rows in an array? For example, `$array = array('qwerty', 'hello world', 'next row', etc');`?

Comment: Hi, just figured it out (sorry it's getting late!) the array is correct, I just wasn't printing anything where the array was blank and thus there were no spaces in my output!

Comment: Hi Dave, that is my ultimate goal, but as it is at the moment I pass each row over as 0, 1, 2 etc and then in the other script I catch each row like that, $one=$_GET['0']; $two=$_GET['two']; etc... I can then create an array from those but it's not essential.